# Cannot install quarto with nbdev_install_quarto - ImportError: cannot import name 'uname' from 'os'

Tags: python, windows, fast-ai, nbdev

I'm trying to install nbdev in my jupyter notebook [as described in this tutorial](https://nbdev.fast.ai/tutorials/tutorial.html) .
I'm trying to run in my CLI this command (after completeing the previous steps that described there):

```
nbdev_install_quarto
```

But I get this error :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'uname' from 'os' (C:\Users\Reut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\os.py). Did you mean: 'name'?
```

I am using Python version 3.12, Operating System - Windows.
I couldn't find the reason for this error,Maybe I should find osname file and change it, but that seems to me to "radical", also, I have nevevr had to do that before with nbdev and I'm afraid to ruin the environment).  could it be that I need to downgrade the Python version I am using? It
What is the right thing to do? how can I tackle this error and make my nbdev environment to work?

Comment: [`os.uname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.uname) is only available on Unix, not Windows. Looks like that tool does not (properly) support Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was having similar type of error while installing nbdev_new. Used the last version of nbdev==2.3.12 and error was solved, you can do the same..