# nbdev_export ; pip install doesn't work on nbdev with windows

Tags: python, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nbdev

I have downloaded nbdev based on [this tutorial][1] and [the help I got in this post][2].
Before I used nbdev on bash , but now unfortunately I have to work with windows.
Now, I have two notebooks, and I want to import function from notebook1 to notebook2.
In order to do this , when I used bash I run this command on the CLI:

```
nbdev_export && pip install ./
```

However, now ,as I  use windows, I tried to run the following command:

```
nbdev_export ; pip install
```

But I receive this error:

```
(.venv) PS C:\git\my_repo> nbdev_export ; pip install
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2 ##this version allowed me to install quarto
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

When I run nbdev_export alone it works, so seems like I only missing the right way to use pip install.

**My question is, how can I apply the "pip install" part in windows?**
[1]: https://nbdev.fast.ai/tutorials/tutorial.html
[2]: [Cannot install quarto with nbdev_install_quarto - ImportError: cannot import name 'uname' from 'os'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77675755/cannot-install-quarto-with-nbdev-install-quarto-importerror-cannot-import-nam/77689819#77689819)

Comment: @Philippe simple and correct! please consider write your answer as a post so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `pip install`, you need to specify the package to install, so this should work :

```
pip install nbdev
```